# GCE instance no longer starts after a sysprep

Tags: google-compute-engine, reboot, sysprep

I have an instance that runs windows server 22 on GCP. The goal is this instance is copying, for that I make a gcesysprep, which does it correctly and turns off my machine. But when I want to access it again to see if it works, the instance is no longer accessible despite being running.
How can I solve this?

Thanks,

I tried to run my sysprep differently, run via gcloud, via windows, via gcesysprep

Comment: Check Cloud Logging for the instance. Are any errors or warnings reported? Connect via serial port 1. You can watch the boot process. Edit your post with more details.